# How to get consistent touch size on Android devices?

Tags: android, touch

I'm working on a drawing app, and want to adjust the size of a brush-stroke depending on how much of the user's finger-tip is being used. I.e. a light touch should produce a thin stroke and using the full finger-tip should produce a thick stroke.

I thought I had it working pretty well, using `MotionEvent.getSize()`, but then found the results are inconsistent. My Galaxy I9000 phone and my 7" Galaxy Tab gave similar results, but a friend's 10.1" Galaxy Note gave very different numbers.

I wrote a test app to try out other options like `getTouchMajor()` and `getPressure()`, but the results were even less consistent.

I did some tests and here are the numbers for getSize()...

```
GTI9000   4.1" light touch = 0.033 medium = 0.1   firm = 0.33
Gal Tab 3   7" light touch = 0.02  medium = 0.1   firm = 0.15
Gal Note 10.1" light touch = 0.008 medium = 0.015 firm = 0.03
```

`getTouchMajor()` gives strange results, with a large touch measuring 10-15 on the I9000, 50-65 on the Tab3, but only around 2.5 on the Note.

I've tried to think of ways to adjust based on resolution, density, etc, but can't find anything that gets consistent results.

Any suggestions appreciated!

EDIT:

@Joseph Earl : Thanks for that great suggestion!  Rather than have a specific calibration, I decided to try just "observing" the size of touch events in a couple of earlier activities (where the user is making a selection), and then use this to determine a rough average.

In my selection activities (there's two) I have added this...

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    App.adjustSize(event.getSize());
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

App is a class that extends Application, and which I use for a few application-wide functions.  Here's a snippet of the relevant parts...

```
static private int mNSizeSamples = 0;
static private float mSizeTotal = 0;
static private float mSizeAvg = 0;

static public void adjustSize(float val) {
    mNSizeSamples++;
    mSizeTotal += val;
    mSizeAvg = mSizeTotal / mNSizeSamples; 
}

static public float getSizeAvg() {
    return mSizeAvg;
}
```

From there I then scale my chosen brush size by dividing by App.getSizeAvg().  So far it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: You could add a calibration utility if no other options present themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, extending on Joseph Earl's suggestion of a calibration utility, I look at the size of early touches to try and establish a base-line.